# I'm getting a NullReferenceException inside MessageHeaderManager.GetHeader when receiving a message with NserviceBus host

Tags: nservicebus

I'm using NServiceBus 3 and when I receive a message I'm getting this error from the receiving endpoint.:

```
NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.Transactional.TransactionalTransport [(null)] <(null)> - Failed raising 'transport message received' event for message with ID=97d0f2fa-6227-439b-ad37-a304bd2af000\10428
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at NServiceBus.MessageHeaders.MessageHeaderManager.GetHeader(Object message, String key)
   at NServiceBus.MessageHeaders.Bootstrapper.<Run>b__0(Object msg, String key)
   at NServiceBus.ExtensionMethods.GetHeader(Object msg, String key)
   at NServiceBus.ExtensionMethods.GetOriginatingSiteHeader(Object msg)
   at NServiceBus.Gateway.HeaderManagement.GatewayHeaderManager.MutateIncoming(Object message)
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.<>c__DisplayClass25.<ApplyIncomingMessageMutatorsTo>b__24(IMutateIncomingMessages m)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.ForEach(Action`1 action)
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.ApplyIncomingMessageMutatorsTo(IBuilder builder, Object originalMessage)
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.<>c__DisplayClass22.<HandleMessage>b__21(Object msg)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.HandleMessage(IBuilder builder, TransportMessage m)
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.HandleTransportMessage(IBuilder childBuilder, TransportMessage msg)
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.TransportMessageReceived(Object sender, TransportMessageReceivedEventArgs e)
   at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.Transactional.TransactionalTransport.OnTransportMessageReceived(TransportMessage msg)
```

The message itself looks like this:

```
public interface ILinkPersonMessage : IBaseMessage
{
    int PersonId { get; set; }
    List<int> UnitIds { get; set; }
}

public interface IBaseMessage
{
    int UserId { get; set; }
}
```

In the sending class I'm doing this:

```
var message = bus.CreateInstance<ILinkPersonMessage>();
message.UserId = currentUser.UserId;
message.PersonId = personId;
message.UnitIds = selectedUnits;

bus.Send(message);
```

**Update:**

I'm looking through the NServiceBus code, and this is the method that's throwing the error:

```
    public string GetHeader(object message, string key)
    {
        if (message == ExtensionMethods.CurrentMessageBeingHandled)
            if (bus.CurrentMessageContext.Headers.ContainsKey(key))
                return bus.CurrentMessageContext.Headers[key];
            else
                return null;

        if (messageHeaders == null)
            return null;

        if (!messageHeaders.ContainsKey(message))
            return null;

        if (messageHeaders[message].ContainsKey(key))
            return messageHeaders[message][key];

        return null;
    }
```

From looking at that code, this could only be happening if `bus.CurrentMessageContext` or `bus.CurrentMessageContext.Headers` are null, or if `messageHeaders[message]` existed, but contained a null value.  Unfortunately I haven't been able to figure out yet which one of these scenarios is more likely (or even possible)

**Update 2**

So using QueueExplorer I've pulled the headers out:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfHeaderInfo xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <HeaderInfo>
        <Key>NServiceBus.Version</Key>
        <Value>3.0.3</Value>
    </HeaderInfo>
    <HeaderInfo>
        <Key>NServiceBus.TimeSent</Key>
        <Value>2012-05-08 06:57:15:691208 Z</Value>
    </HeaderInfo>
    <HeaderInfo>
        <Key>NServiceBus.EnclosedMessageTypes</Key>
        <Value>Namespace.Service.ILinkPersonMessage __impl, NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport__impl, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null;Namespace.Service.ILinkPersonMessage, Namespace.Service, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null</Value>
    </HeaderInfo>
    <HeaderInfo>
        <Key>WinIdName</Key>
        <Value>*{myusername}*</Value>
    </HeaderInfo>
    <HeaderInfo>
        <Key>CorrId</Key>
    </HeaderInfo>
</ArrayOfHeaderInfo>
```

**Update 3**

This is the fluent config that now works:

```
Configure.With()
.DefiningEventsAs(t => t.Namespace != null && t.Namespace.StartsWith("Events"))
.DefiningCommandsAs(t => t.Namespace != null && t.Namespace.StartsWith("Messages"))
.CastleWindsorBuilder(container)
.XmlSerializer()
.MsmqTransport()
.IsTransactional(true)
.IsolationLevel(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted)
.UnicastBus()
.RavenSagaPersister()
.RavenSubscriptionStorage()
.UseRavenTimeoutPersister()
.RunTimeoutManager()
.ForInstallationOn<NServiceBus.Installation.Environments.Windows>().Install();
```

(I've trimmed all the namespaces)

Comment: FYI: I can't see how a missing header could cause the NRE, but NServiceBus.ExtensionMethods.GetOriginatingSiteHeader() in your stack trace is looking for the "NServiceBus.OriginatingSite" header, not in your headers.

Comment: So if I add .UnicastBus() to the fluent config, it starts working, even though when the service starts up it tells me the UnicastBus is already registered in the container.  I think I still don't understand well enough what's going on under the hood

Comment: Can you post the entire fluent config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this happen on the first message after sending process startup, or just subsequent ones?

Are you configuring your sending bus more than once? (NServiceBus.Configure?)

Comment: Are you configuring a web sender - Configure.WithWeb()?

Comment: Yeah, it's a web sender, the receiver is running NserviceBus.Host.  I don't *think* I'm configuring the sender more than once, I can't see more that one IConfigureThisEndpoint implementer.

Comment: It's happening on every message, not just the 1st one

Comment: We had a situation where the web sender was calling var bus=NServiceBus.Configure.WithWeb().Blah().Blah() on each call. This caused the FIRST message to have the required headers (and the receiver was ok), but SUBSEQUENT ones wouldn't - resulting in a very similar stack trace (on the receiver).
Where are you getting "bus" from for "bus.Send()"?

Comment: It's being dependency injected in to the MVC controller, lifetyle of singleton

Answer (score 1):

We've recently fixed some bugs around the header management so it could be that that's what you were running into. Please try upgrading to 3.0.4 and see if that resolves your issues.

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happened to me, the problem was that i forgot to setup the xmlserialization when configuring the service bus

```
var configBus = NServiceBus.Configure.With()
.DefaultBuilder()
.MsmqSubscriptionStorage()
.XmlSerializer() // <== This line here
.MsmqTransport()
    .IsTransactional(true)
    .PurgeOnStartup(false)
.UnicastBus()
.ImpersonateSender(true);
```